# How to re lock bootloader on samsung galaxy s5?

Tags: root-access, samsung, bootloader

I have Unlocked Rooted Samsung Galaxy S5 recently it has been giving me a lot of issues and I want to send it to Samsung for repair meant. I understand that once you root your device you loose the warranty, but recently I was doing research and I found out if you re lock your bootloader and unroot your device you can get your warranty back, so can some one tell me how to do it ? and if you can tell me if there is a way to find out even if your bootloader is locked or unlocked ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't get your warranty back, you hide that you unlocked and rooted in the first place (so you never "actually" lost warranty) . I don't know Samsung devices all that well, have you tried booting into fastboot and doing "fastboot oem lock"? If your device doesn't have fastboot obviously this won't work. Usually carriers and the phone companies can find out bootloader status by booting into bootloader with" adb reboot bootloader" or some key combination.

Tip: if you are using SuperSU as your superuser app, there will be an unroot option in it. Good luck!

Comment: To add to this: Not all devices support re-locking. Some (e.g. LG) using [fuses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_%28electrical%29) which you simply "burn" when unlocking, so no way back from there (once "burnt", the state of a fuse cannot be reverted). Not sure which applies to the S5.

Comment: @Izzy I've heard some Motorola phones use this too. For example, a moto g (which I just so happens to have) would show bootloader status "relocked", instead of "locked"

Comment: That's a third variant it seems. I don't know if that possibility even exists at all with LG devices...

Comment: Samsung use a multi faceted approach: they have a counter for how many times custom firmware has been flashed, triangle away used to be able to change this, and there is a 'custom/original' indicator for the firmware. Thirdly is Samsung Knox, if that is tripped from 0x0 to 0x1 there is no way to set it back on the device that I am aware of. It's down to the service centre, the *could* say the warranty is void, but generally they seem to be servicing them from anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an unlocked bootloader on your s5. I know this, because to date, there is no known unlock method for the bootloader. To restore to stock, uninstall safestrap (if applicable) then use Odin or Heimdal to flash a factory image.

Comment: He does not say what carrier he has, the T-mobile variant has an unlocked bootloader, out of the box. [You can't flash a custom recovery on a locked bootloader](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51833400&postcount=158).

Comment: @RyanConrad SAMSUNG HAS NO BOOTLOADERS

Answer (score 0):

Samsung has a different fastboot mode called the Odin mode. It's easy to access. Power off your device and press the volume down+home button+power button to go to the Odin mode. You can use the Odin app to flash the stock ROM and hence you can easily hide the fact that you have rooted the phone. This is one way to get the warranty back if you have rooted you phone. It's a pretty simple technique and you can use it to being your phone back to life if you softbrick your phone. Google up to find tutorials for your phone as to how to use the Odin mode to get back to stock ROM.

Answer (score -1):

Basically for rooting a device you need to unlock the boot loader so that you can format the stock O.S which is supposed to boot on switching ON the device and replace with a custom OS.You can check whether the device boot loader is locked or unlocked by connecting your device via the ADB debug drivers to the Android develop tools(ADT).

(OR)

Simply `*#*#7378423#*#*` >Service Info> Configuration.

Bootloader unlock allowed - Yes:- this means that your Bootloader is Locked
Bootloader Unlocked - Yes << this means that your bootloader is unlocked

**Note**:-It all depends on the manufacturer of the phone as well as the Telecom Operator.Some provide detailed steps to unlock the boot loader and some don't.Whereas in some cases the Operator itself may lock the boot loader (not the phone lock but the boot loader lock) for reasons known to them

Comment: do i dial  ##7378423## ? or whats up ?

Comment: try the dial number.i don't know from where what's up came into picture